# Show only taxonomy types terms associated with a custom post type in WordPress PHP

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I am trying to display only the taxonomy types terms selected on a custom post type "newsroom". The code below shows all taxonomy types terms for every type of post. Is there a way to show only the types terms tagged on a post under the custom post type "newsroom"?

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="resource_filter">
    <?php
        if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'types', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) { // types
            ?> <div class="types-filter"><h3>Types</h3> <?php
          foreach ( $terms as $term ){ ?>
            <label class="MuiFormControlLabel-root">
                <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss317 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorSecondary MuiIconButton-colorSecondary" aria-disabled="false">
                    <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="types_filter[]" id="checkbox_types_filter_<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" class="resource-filter-checkbox" value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" data-indeterminate="false" data_term_name="<?php echo $term->name; ?>">
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiFormControlLabel-label MuiTypography-body1">
                    <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2"><?php echo $term->name; ?></p>
                </span>
            </label>
          <?php 
            }
          ?> 
          </div> 
    <?php
        } ?>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

The custom SQL query below can be used to produce a list of unique **types** taxonomy terms that have been assigned to **newsroom** posts. In PHP, you can call the function **get_newsroom_types_terms** to get the list: `$terms = get_newsroom_types_terms();`.

## Custom SQL query

```
function get_newsroom_types_terms() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $taxonomy = 'types';
    $post_type = 'newsroom';

    $sql = <<<EOSQL
        SELECT DISTINCT T.term_id, T.name, T.slug
        FROM {$table_prefix}terms T
        JOIN {$table_prefix}term_taxonomy TT ON ( TT.term_id = T.term_id )
        JOIN {$table_prefix}term_relationships TR ON ( TR.term_taxonomy_id = TT.term_taxonomy_id )
        JOIN {$table_prefix}posts P ON ( P.ID = TR.object_id )
        WHERE TT.taxonomy = %s
            AND P.post_type = %s
        ORDER BY T.name
    EOSQL;

    $query = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $taxonomy, $post_type );

    $terms = $wpdb->get_results( $query, \OBJECT );

    return $terms;
}
```

## HTML Form

Please see [my comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/421343/show-only-taxonomy-types-terms-associated-with-a-custom-post-type-in-wordpress-p/421346#comment613313_421346).

The PHP/HTML code for the form has several problems.

1. It partially hardcodes the URL for **admin-ajax.php**.
2. **admin-ajax.php** is not requested from an AJAX call.
3. There is no indication of the default state for checkboxes.
4. There is no code indicating how checkbox states are updated.
5. Material-UI class names are hardcoded even though Material-UI uses ReactJS to render its HTML.

Please read the WordPress Documentation on [How Do I Use AJAX?](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/#how-do-i-use-ajax)

Comment: Nothing shows up with this. I am trying to get the terms of the "types" to show up.

Comment: I've updated my answer with code to get the terms. The PHP/HTML code for the form has several problems making it difficult to figure out what you are trying to accomplish. It appears you want to: *filter [posts] through [**types** terms] and also search input to filter them only for the custom post type "newsroom"*. After submitting the form should a list of **newsroom** posts appear like an archive page filtered by the selected **types** terms and also a text-input search field? If not, what should happen when the user submits the form? Did you intend to add a text-input field to this form?

Comment: Yes, there is an input field for search. 
<div class="resource-listing-filter-section resource-listing-filter-section-desk">
            <form role="search" method="POST" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_type_archive_link( 'newsroom' ) ); ?>" >
                <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search..." />
                <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="newsroom" />
                <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
            </form>

Comment: I may need to re-ask this question with the entire archive-newsroom.php template code. It's just a lot of code.

Comment: This is working in showing the type terms on with newsroom posts, but when filtering them the result display all results along with the header and footer of the website in the results div element. I am using this action on the form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_type_archive_link( 'newsroom' ) )

Comment: Before re-asking your question, could you please explain how/where users would access the search form? From what I see, the search will not work as intended. When you use reserved WordPress query variables in a URL, WP will use them to target a template according to the Template Hierarchy, and could ignore your `<form>` *action* (the newsroom archive template). Have you considered using a modified (default) WordPress search form? Your original `<form>` targeted an AJAX endpoint. Did you intend to have search results returned to the client via AJAX? Or was it a mistake to use `admin-ajax.php`?

Comment: The form is on the same page as the results. The results load on the same page in a <div>. It is explained more in this question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/421484/search-and-filter-terms-of-a-custom-post-type-only-and-display-results

Comment: Users access the search form input field and checkboxes in the archive-newsroom.php template which has the path of /newsroom/

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, you can retrieve the taxonomy types associated with a custom post type using the get_object_taxonomies() function. This function retrieves the names or objects of the taxonomies associated with a specific post type.

Here's an example of how you can use this function in WordPress PHP to get the taxonomy types associated with a custom post type:

```
// Replace 'your_post_type' with the name of your custom post type
$post_type = 'your_post_type';

// Get taxonomies associated with the custom post type
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);

// Output the taxonomy types
if (!empty($taxonomies)) {
    echo 'Taxonomy types associated with custom post type ' . $post_type . ':<br>';
    foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
        echo $taxonomy . '<br>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No taxonomies found for the custom post type ' . $post_type;
}
```

Replace 'your_post_type' with the slug or name of your actual custom post type. This code will retrieve and display the taxonomy types associated with that custom post type.

Comment: This just gives me the types, but not the actual type that is selected for posts in the custom post type.
Taxonomy types associated with custom post type newsroom:
category
post_tag
types
topics