# Get a custom post type's taxonomy type term names displayed as checkboxes and filter

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, taxonomy, search, terms

I using this code to get all the taxonomies associated with a custom post type "newsroom"

```
$post_type = 'newsroom';

// Get taxonomies associated with the custom post type
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);

// Output the taxonomy types
if (!empty($taxonomies)) {
    echo 'Taxonomy types associated with custom post type ' . $post_type . ':<br>';
    foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
        echo $taxonomy . '<br>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No taxonomies found for the custom post type ' . $post_type;
}
```

Which results in

> Taxonomy types associated with custom post type newsroom:
> category
> post_tag
> types
> topics

How do I display the names of the "types" terms that are selected on the posts under the custom post type "newsroom"? I am trying to display them as checkboxes so I can filter through them and also search input to filter them only for the custom post type "newsroom".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show only taxonomy types terms associated with a custom post type in WordPress PHP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/421343/show-only-taxonomy-types-terms-associated-with-a-custom-post-type-in-wordpress-p)