# Search and filter terms of a custom post type only and display results

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, search, terms

I am creating an archive-newsroom.php for my /newsroom page and custom post type. I have the custom post type working, but now I am trying to have a search input to display the custom post type results and filtering with terms as checkboxes that are assigned to the posts only in the post type "newsroom". How do I have search only search "newsroom" and how do I only display the terms assigned to posts in the custom post type "newsroom". Then how do I display the results?

I am trying to achieve all of this without installing a plugin. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Search and term checkboxes

```
<div class="resource-listing-filter-section resource-listing-filter-section-desk">
        <div class="types-filter search-filter">
            <h3>Search</h3>
            <form role="search" method="POST" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_type_archive_link( 'newsroom' ) ); ?>" >
                <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search..." />
                <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="newsroom" />
                <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_type_archive_link( 'newsroom' ) ); ?>" method="POST" id="filter">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="torch_newsroom_filter">
            <?php
                if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'types', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ){ 
                    ?> <div class="types-filter"><h3>Types</h3> <?php
                  foreach ( $terms as $term ){ ?>
                    <label class="MuiFormControlLabel-root">
                        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss317 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorSecondary MuiIconButton-colorSecondary" aria-disabled="false">
                            <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox_types_filter_<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" class="resource-filter-checkbox" value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" data-indeterminate="false" data_term_name="<?php echo $term->name; ?>">
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiFormControlLabel-label MuiTypography-body1">
                            <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2"><?php echo $term->name; ?></p>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                  <?php }
                  ?> </div> <?php
                } ?>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Posts output

````
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'newsroom',
                'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
                'posts_per_page' => 12,//-1 for all, set same number in functions.php.
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => '_thumbnail_id', 
                         'compare' => '!NOT EXISTS' // include post with _thumbnail_id key
                    ),
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        'resource_library_no_rank_clause' => array(
                            'key' => 'resource_library_list_rank',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                        ),
                        'resource_library_has_rank_clause' => array(
                            'key' => 'resource_library_list_rank',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                        ),
                        'resource_library_rank_clause' => array(
                            'key' => 'resource_library_list_rank',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'compare' => '>0'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'orderby' => array(
                    'resource_library_rank_clause' => 'DESC',
                    'date' => 'DESC'
                ),
                'tax_query' =>  array(
                    array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'category',
                      'terms' => 'engineering', // Taxonomy Term that I wanted to exclude
                      'field' => 'slug', // Whether I am passing term Slug or term ID
                      'operator' => 'NOT IN', // Selection operator - use IN to include, NOT IN to exclude
                    ),
                  ),

            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ```
````

Comment: The question has at least five sub-questions: 1. How to use a custom search input text field. 2. How to limit search results to a custom post type. 3. How to render search form checkboxes representing terms from a custom taxonomy. 4. How to filter a custom post type search using submitted form checkboxes. 5. How to render search results on a custom post type archive page. Your code already answers sub-question **#2** (`$args = array( 'post_type' => 'newsroom', ... )`). The remaining sub-questions might each require their own separate WP Stack Exchange question (and some background research).

Comment: Some hints: Avoid using [reserved WP query variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars) as form field names. When processing the submitted form, get form field values using `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`. Substitute the retrieved form field values in the arguments used for the call to `new WP\_Query( $args )`. When configuring `$args` to use the form's search text input field, you have to manually decide what Post fields should be searched. You may have to use [posts_clauses](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_clauses/) for fuzzy searching, and know how to code SQL.